# Is it possible to use Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) inside Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, webkit, windows-store-apps, chromium, chromium-embedded

How to integrate Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) inside Windows Store (Metro Style) App. I read CEF Wiki - https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/ but did not find anything related to Windows Store Apps. There is tutorial for WPF app - https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/Tutorial And there is a example for WPF App - cefclient. Is there any example for Windows Store apps? I want to create a CEF webview inside Windows Store App.

Answer (score 6):

We tried that, but the problem was distributing CEF binaries along with Windows store app which would not app certification. We are using WebView provided by Windows store app programming to render web content. We could interact with rendered javascript with ScriptNotify and InvokeScriptAsync.

Please look into http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx if are interested in details