# Is it possible to use the chrome engine in my windows app?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, d3.js, uwp

I am developing an app in windows 10 (UWP) and I am using the D3 engine for some visualizations. As I have found out it's using Microsofts Edge engine to render everything, obviously it doesn't handle D3's animations as well as Chrome does.

Is there a way to attach the chrome engine to my app to render the animations sufficiently enough without any lag ?

I have searched around and found out about 'ChromeEmbedded', can anyone tell me if this is the correct way to go : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can pull this off. ( [Is it possible to use Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) inside Windows Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156023/is-it-possible-to-use-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-inside-windows-store-app/24225932#24225932) ) And even if you could https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx §10.2.1 and §10.2.2 probably prohibits you from doing this.

Comment: thanks for the links. Does that mean I could use it if i dont deploy to store ? Have you got experience with this ?

Comment: Maybe - with windows 10 the winrt.. I mean UWP apis got more permissive. I'd ask http://stackoverflow.com/users/3674740/praveen-rao-joginapally :)